# Oracle SQl Developer Reports

Tags: oracle, report

My objective is to create a User Defined Report in SQL Developer by querying multiple tables. But am unable to create a report with multiple select queries.

So I have tried using UNION ALL between the select queries and I got the count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_A WHERE ..
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_B WHERE ..
....
```

With this query, I have got the count of data alone. But, I would actually need the table name and the count.

```
Table_name  Count
A            10
B            10
C            10
D            10
E            10
```

Could someone provide a better approach

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` can be made to work. You'd do something like:

```
SELECT TBLA_FLD1, TBLA_FLD2, TBLA_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLB_FLD1, NULL AS TBLB_FLD2, NULL AS TBLB_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLC_FLD1, NULL AS TBLC_FLD2, NULL AS TBLC_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLD_FLD1, NULL AS TBLD_FLD2, NULL AS TBLD_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLE_FLD1, NULL AS TBLE_FLD2, NULL AS TBLE_FLD3
  FROM TABLE_A UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS TBLA_FLD1, NULL AS TBLA_FLD2, NULL AS TBLA_FLD3,
       TBLB_FLD1, TBLB_FLD2, TBLB_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLC_FLD1, NULL AS TBLC_FLD2, NULL AS TBLC_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLD_FLD1, NULL AS TBLD_FLD2, NULL AS TBLD_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLE_FLD1, NULL AS TBLE_FLD2, NULL AS TBLE_FLD3
  FROM TABLE_B UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS TBLA_FLD1, NULL AS TBLA_FLD2, NULL AS TBLA_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLB_FLD1, NULL AS TBLB_FLD2, NULL AS TBLB_FLD3,
       TBLC_FLD1, TBLC_FLD2, TBLC_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLD_FLD1, NULL AS TBLD_FLD2, NULL AS TBLD_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLE_FLD1, NULL AS TBLE_FLD2, NULL AS TBLE_FLD3
  FROM TABLE_C UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS TBLA_FLD1, NULL AS TBLA_FLD2, NULL AS TBLA_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLB_FLD1, NULL AS TBLB_FLD2, NULL AS TBLB_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLC_FLD1, NULL AS TBLC_FLD2, NULL AS TBLC_FLD3,
       TBLD_FLD1, TBLD_FLD2, TBLD_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLE_FLD1, NULL AS TBLE_FLD2, NULL AS TBLE_FLD3
  FROM TABLE_D UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS TBLA_FLD1, NULL AS TBLA_FLD2, NULL AS TBLA_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLB_FLD1, NULL AS TBLB_FLD2, NULL AS TBLB_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLC_FLD1, NULL AS TBLC_FLD2, NULL AS TBLC_FLD3,
       NULL AS TBLD_FLD1, NULL AS TBLD_FLD2, NULL AS TBLD_FLD3,
       TBLE_FLD1, TBLE_FLD2, TBLE_FLD3
  FROM TABLE_E UNION ALL
```

It may not be pretty, but it may be your only option.

Best of luck.